# Accessing Mulit-dimensional non indexed array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am getting this array with a `var_dump($data);`

```
array (size=1)
  'sambalpur25.com' => 
    array (size=2)
      'classkey' => string 'domcno' (length=6)
      'status' => string 'available' (length=9)
```

Now I want to access the value of `status` from the array, I have tried it multiple ways, but couldn't get the result.

I have attempted like below without any success;

```
var_dump($data[0]['status']);exit;
var_dump($data['status']);exit;


foreach($data as $key => $val){
            echo $data[$key]; 
            }
```

Comment: Why ignore `'sambalpur25.com'`? `var_dump($data['sambalpur25.com']['status']);` The indentation is helpful ;-)

Comment: I don't know what value will come at the place of `sambalpur25.com`. Visitor may insert any value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach($data as $key => $val){
    $classkey = $val['classkey'];
    $status = $val['status'];
}
```

You were close, in this case $key is 'sambalpur25.com' and $val is the array at that index. If you're fine to iterate over it like that, then use $val.

Answer (score 0):

the structure is an array, inside of an object, so this should work (but you need to give a name to your array (for example "matthew"):

**matthew->sambalpur25.com["status"]**
or
**matthew.sambalpur25.com["status"]**